# Error on Inserting values in sybase table using Python script

Tags: python, sybase

```
cursor = db.cursor()
query = """create table tempdb..fi_kundan(firstname varchar(9),symbol
varchar(9),lastname varchar(12))"""
cursor.execute(query)
f = open("./extractS1","r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
  word = line.split('|')
  a = word[0]
  b = word[1]
  c = word[2]
  cursor.execute("insert into tempdb..fi_kundan values (?,?,?)",(a,b,c))
```

I have connected to an Informix database and I am trying to insert values into the table that I am creating using this Python script. The values to be inserted are coming from a file. But I am getting the following error in running this script.

Can someone please suggest what's wrong here.

error message:

```
for name, value in params.items():
```

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
>       
>       Exception Sybase.DatabaseError: DatabaseError('Layer: 1, Origin: 1\nct_cmd_drop(): user
>        api layer: external error: This routine can be called only if the command structure is
>        idle.',) in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <Sybase.Cursor instance at 0x12bb20>>
>        ignored

Thanks !

Comment: In which file/module is that `for name, value in params.items()` loop? It's clearly expecting a dictionary and getting a tuple.

Comment: How the code is binded to the error?

Comment: Just to check, and I may be barking up the wrong tree, and I may be 2 days late. But have your inserted values got quotes round them? You'll need that if inserting into varchar fields.